# Batch file to recursively find files named a specific name and move to a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion

So, I was hit with the Cryptowall 3.0 ransomware virus. After decryption I am still left with a large amount of DECRYPT_HELP files in .txt, .html, .png and Windows Shortcut formats.

I need a batch script to recursively find the files containing the name "DECRYPT_HELP" regardless of its' extension and move those files into a directory which I will delete.

I am a Linux guy, so I can't FIND and GREP my way through this. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Would using `RoboCopy` be an option?  Robocopy has an option to `/MOVE : Move files and dirs (delete from source after copying).` So I'd use `Robocopy c:\ d:\dest\ *decrypt_help* /S /MOVE /R:5 /W:5 /`

Comment: FYI, you can install those linux utils, see [gnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html). Take a look at the _CoreUtils_, _FindUtils_, and _Grep_ packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the files using

```
dir /s *decrypt_help*
```

**dangerous command follows**

```
del /s *decrypt_help*
```

will delete all of those files. **use with extreme caution**